# Array Calculation with CSV file

Tags: vb.net, arrays, csv

I am trying to work with taking in and parsing CSV files. Right now I have it taking in and producing something like this:

[image]

The program loads the csv and copies the data into an array as such:

```
ReDim strarray(num_rows, num_cols)
For x = 0 To num_rows
  strline = strlines(x).Split(",")
  For y = 0 To num_cols
    strarray(x, y) = strline(y)
  Next
Next
```

The CSV file data is very basic formatted with two columns and x number of rows:

```
212, 343
324, 232
```

etc. I guess my main problem is trying to perform calculations to all values in a specific column. To start I am just trying to figure out how to isolate the columns and found that by using MsgBox(strarray(x, num_cols)) it will msgbox everything in the second column twice. I just want to try and understand how I can perform a basic calculation like multiply every value in the first column by 2 and every value in the second column one by 3.

Comment: Note: The CSV file should not contain a space after the comma.

Answer (score 0):

To start with: In VB arrays go from 0 to number of items minus 1. However you will have specify the maximum index, not the size:

```
Dim x As String() = new String(N-1) 'Where N is the number of items.
Dim y As String() = new String(MAX) 'Where MAX is the highest index.
```

And you have integer numbers. So you would have to declare:

```
Dim matrix As Integer(,) = new Integer(num_rows-1, num_cols-1)
```

And then fill it with:

```
For row As Integer = 0 To num_rows-1
    Dim strline As String() = strlines(row).Split(",")
    For col As Integer = 0 To num_cols-1
        matrix(row, col) = Integer.Parse(strline(col))
    Next                 
Next
```

Example calculation:

```
For row As Integer = 0 To num_rows-1
    matrix(row,0) *= 2
    matrix(row,1) *= 3
Next
```